# How can I efficiently pick up bricks off the floor?

Tags: cleaning

My floor is covered in bricks. My bare feet can't take much more abuse. Is there a way of collecting up the bricks easily, or should I just get on my knees and start scooping them up with my hands?

Comment: Probably - now you mention it, I remember using the Technic front loader shovel in a similar way - forgot about that though as it's been sitting in a box in the loft for too long...

Comment: I use small children - well, it's usually their fault, so they might as well be tasked with picking them all up again!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I actually have somewhere a special Lego picking up device. It has two wheels on the sides and when you slide it across the floor, these turn an attachment at the front. The attachement is basically like the thing on the side of a paddle boat, but taking up the whole width of the front, and it throws the lego pieces into the back of the device as it turns. It works marvelously on carpets!

*Edit:* It's a [Brick Vac](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/1666_Brick_Vac).

[image: Brick vac picture]

Comment: Found it! I shall not be insulted if you bow to the master of Google-Fu. :) Hey, I meant me!

Comment: Thank you!! I couldn't find it earlier on. Also, although thee picture show what is technically Duplo, it works brilliantly on Lego and Lego Technic.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to make an automated Mindstorms robot doing just that

Answer (score 11):

I know the sheet-on-the-carpet idea has been mentionned already, but why not go for a full LEGO solution?

[image: http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=787-1]

And if you want another pure LEGO solution, I give you… the Brick-O-Dile!

[image]

Comment: While a bag solves the OP's problem, the bricks rapidly become mixed with dust, hair and other filth. So, from one problem to another.

Answer (score 10):

The best idea is just using prevention: Put a big white cloth on the floor, and when you want to clean up, put the corners together and collect the parts from the middle.

Comment: This is what my brother and I did as children

Comment: Wow when I first read that I saw "That is what my brother and I did *with* children"

Answer (score 10):

I like to get out my [Loader-Dozer](http://www.rockraidersunited.org/wiki/index.php?title=4950_Loader-Dozer) (from LEGO Rock Raiders) to clean up my bricks:

[image]

Obviously this is inspired from the video game, in which the same vehicle serves to remove rubble:

[image]

I'm so meta like that.

Comment: "Loh-dah Doeser"

Comment: @Pubby8: "Ruh-bull"

Comment: Let me guess... "-1 for nostalgia"? Wait, that's not right...

Answer (score 9):

A dustpan & brush will do a good job:

[image: hand brush + dustpan]

Just make sure you don't pick up too much dust with the bricks!

Comment: It's called a dustpan, not a shovel ;)

Comment: thanks for the hint, i changed that - i'm not a native english speaker, so i just translated the german "handfeger und schaufel" ;)

Comment: It's commonly called "a brush and shovel" in Aotearoa and I suspect at least parts of Scotland.

Answer (score 3):

Hoover. Or bare feet. They both work well ;)

Seriously though, I'm a bare hands kind of guy if I've not followed the instructions, and split them all over the floor as opposed to doing it on the table or a large butlers tray.

Comment: I agree about the bare hands technique!  Also, my young dog is quite adept at finding the pieces.

Comment: I seem to remember Hoover made one specific model which was LEGO-friendly; that is, LEGO parts were supposed to go in another compartment. They even offered a small set with it.

Comment: We have a bagless vacuum cleaner and it works quite well, but it does rattle the pieces round a lot and I suspect damages them.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to prevent them from getting into the carpet, is to first spread the Lego over a sheet that's on the ground.  Then you can just pick up the corners and dump the pieces back where they are stored.

Answer (score 1):

We have a rule that you only play with LEGO at the dining room table. The pieces are too little to be played with efficiently on the floor. It's much easier to tidy away as you have a smaller space that you can sweep into a box. Any small piece that gets dropped is picked up by the Roomba iRobot!

Comment: The question is not about the merits of playing on the floor but about what to do to pick up pieces once they're on the floor.  On the other hand, I also prefer to build on the table so I don't lose pieces.

Answer (score 1):

I am using my Lego  Remote-Controlled Volvo L350F Wheel Loader (42030 set number) just pushing them into a one big pile and then using my own hands.